# center logo between two menus in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to center the logo. And separate my menu in two parts. I can achieve this by using css but the problem is, how could I insert the logo within li. As complete menu is creates by a function only.
The menu is creating by this code:

```
<div class="logo"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo $qode_options_central['logo_image']; ?>" alt="Logo"/></a></div>
            <div class="header_inner_right">
                <?php
                $menu_type = $qode_options_central['top_menu'];

                ?>
                <nav class="main_menu <?php  if($menu_type == "drop_down") { echo "drop_down"; } elseif($menu_type == "drop_down2") { echo "drop_down2"; } else { echo "drop_down"; } ?>">
                <?php

                    if($menu_type == "drop_down") :
                        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-navigation' , 
                                                                'container'  => '', 
                                                                'container_class' => '', 
                                                                'menu_class' => '', 
                                                                'menu_id' => '',
                                                                'fallback_cb' => 'top_navigation_fallback',
                                                                'walker' => new qode_type1_walker_nav_menu()
                     ));

                    elseif($menu_type == "drop_down2"):
                        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-navigation' , 
                                                                'container'  => '', 
                                                                'container_class' => '', 
                                                                'menu_class' => '', 
                                                                'menu_id' => '',
                                                                'fallback_cb' => 'top_navigation_fallback',
                                                                'walker' => new qode_type2_walker_nav_menu()
                         ));


                    else :
                        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-navigation' , 
                                                                'container'  => '', 
                                                                'container_class' => '', 
                                                                'menu_class' => '', 
                                                                'menu_id' => '',
                                                                'fallback_cb' => 'top_navigation_fallback',
                                                                'walker' => new qode_type1_walker_nav_menu()
                         ));
                    endif;
                ?>

                </nav>

                <div class='selectnav_button'><span>&nbsp;</span></div>

                <?php   
                $display_header_widget = $qode_options_central['header_widget_area'];
                if($display_header_widget == "yes"){ ?> 
                    <div class="header_right_widget">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('header_right'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>
```

I want to separate the menu in two part.I want something like this:

http://local.obcasio.com/Untitled-3.png

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Define two menu's in functions.php and add the menu items to each of them accordingly from your admin panel

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. Actually I am new to wordpress. Can you please give me the example code?

Comment: See this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus you can register multiple menu's give one menu name left-menu another one right-menu. Then in your markup put the output of both the menu's, now from MENU panel you can set 3 menu items on left-menu and three on right-menu.

Comment: hmm ... surely a problem with this approach is that it's not great for responsive sites when shown on a mobile as you end up with two top menus